# Looking for an external service

Tags: local-storage

I don't really know what type into Google.

So the idea is that I host a static SPA (on Github Pages or something) and all required data are written to local storage. User can optionally register using some external service. Literally all I need is REST endpoints to read and write some data (less than 100kb). Ideally there should be SSO for Google, Facebook etc. Cheap enough for a hobby project.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that LoginRadius will do.

It supports SSO and I can write arbitrary data to it: https://www.loginradius.com/docs/developer/api/account-api